manifest merger fail
executing the code in Android studio
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 20 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0] C:\Users\GMI\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\beba06c4e19413cf1745e43fcb83557a\transformed\appcompat-resources-1.7.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 20
  Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 20,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.appcompat.resources" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)


Have you tried the provided suggestions?
